# Template Binary Search Tree ostream overloading issue

Tags: c++, data-structures, operator-overloading

I tried to search but I couldn't find a solution and what is the meaning of the problem.

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const BST<T> &rhs);
void helperFunc(ostream & os, Node<T> *root) const;
```

and the definition is:

```
template<class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const BST<T> &rhs)
{
    rhs.helperFunc(os, rhs._root);
    os << endl;

return os;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::helperFunc(ostream & os, Node<T> *root) const
{
    if (root != NULL)
{
    helperFunc(os, root->left);
    os << root->value << " ";
    helperFunc(os, root->right);
    }
}
```

In main I'm using:

```
void main()
{
BST <int> a;
a.insert(5)
cout << a;
}
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class BST<int> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$BST@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main...
```

Any additional info will be supplied if required.

The solution was:

```
template <typename U>
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const BST<U> &obj);
```

Comment: Have you put the definitions of the functions in the header file?

Comment: Not the cause, but it should be `int main()`.

Comment: Do you have the same function signatures in the header and source files? You are missing `template<class T>` in your function declarations above.

Comment: I agree about the void thing, I kinda rushed to write it. And all this is in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading operator<< and operator>> in template class is a little special. Just comment this declaration and it will work:

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const BST<T> &rhs);
```

**This is because the friend function is not a member function of the class actually. The overloaded operator<< function defined outside the class actually defines a new template function, different from that declared in the class. Although they have the same 'template class T', but indeed they are different functions. So the compile error tells you that the operator<< function of the class is not defined.**

Since we have overload a new template operator<< outside the class, we can just get rid of the friend function declared in the class. The follow codes will work and I change some other functions for well explanation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node {

};

template<class T>
class BST {
public:
// friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const BST<int> &rhs);
    void helperFunc(ostream & os, Node<T> *root) const;
};

template<class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const BST<T> &rhs)
{
    cout << "success" << endl;
    // rhs.helperFunc(os, rhs._root);
    // os << endl;

    return os;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::helperFunc(ostream & os, Node<T> *root) const
{
    if (root != NULL)
{
    helperFunc(os, root->left);
    os << root->value << " ";
    helperFunc(os, root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    BST<int> a;
    // a.insert(5);
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: I'm having one problem with this, If it isn't a friend how can I access the private variable of the root?